# Override paste operation ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

When a user pastes into a ListBox, I want the contents in the clipboard to get arranged as individual items.  Splitting the text will be done by newline character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have `ListBox` control on your form (let's call it `listBox`), you should handle its `KeyDown` event.

Here's the example:

```
private void listBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check that the button pressed is V, that Control is also pressed and that the clipboard contains text.
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.V) && e.Control && Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        // Get text from clipboard and separate it.
        string text = Clipboard.GetText();
        string[] textLines = text.Split(
            new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // or don't

        // Add lines to listBox items.
        listBox.Items.AddRange(textLines);

        // Mark event as handled.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```